# Кнопка во фрейме

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, html5

Всем здравствуйте, у меня есть три фрейма

```
<!DOCTYPE  HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
.button1 {   width:100%;
            height:40px; 
 }
 </style> 
 </head> 

 <frameset cols="29%,*">
 <frameset rows="20%,80%">
    <frame src="left/search.html">
    <frame src="left/tree.php">
  </frameset>
  <frame name ="TABLE" src="right/clean.html">
  <noframes>Ваш браузер не отображает фреймы</noframes>
  </frameset>
  </html>
```

Как мне добавить кнопку, чтобы при нажатии на нее он переходил на предыдущую страницу?

```
<form action="../Originals.html">
<button class="button1">Выход</button></form>
```

Если я добавляю в новый фрейм, то он переходит внутри этого фрейма, а просто на страницу вне фреймсета добавить не выходит=(
Ее нужно сделать либо внешней,либо чтобы по нажатию она выходила не из одного фрейма, а изо всех.Ни то, ни то я не могу нагуглить и сам не знаю, как сделать=(

Comment: 21 век, 2019 год... на фреймах ещё кто-то пишет?!

Comment: @КапитанФлинт я делаю дерево и содержание дерева, мне это удобно использовать,т.к. надо постоянно обновлять только один фрейм, а не всю страницу, плюс это для корпоративного пользования  и индексация поиска здесь не нужна. Так вы не знаете, как сделать подобную кнопку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому-то понадобится, я нашел решение:

```
<button onclick='window.parent.location.href="../../Originals.html";'>Выход</button>
```

Выходит из фреймов на новую страницу в текущей вкладке браузера